# socket.io-stream process is not defined on Vue frontend

Tags: node.js, typescript, vue.js, socket.io, node-streams

I'm writing a program with a Vue3 frontend that may need to send large files to the backend express server. I'm using socket.io to handle the connection between the 2 so I was trying to use socket.io-stream to stream the file to the backend but I'm getting this error:

```
ReferenceError: process is not defined
    js util.js:109
    __require chunk-FAW2VN4A.js:4
    js socket.js:1
    __require chunk-FAW2VN4A.js:4
    js index.js:1
    __require chunk-FAW2VN4A.js:4
    js index.js:2
    __require chunk-FAW2VN4A.js:4
    <anonymous> socket__io-stream.js:3143
```

This is weird to me as I'm not using the process object at any point in my frontend code and looking at the call stack of the error it seems like the problem stems from the module itself.

This is the code I have

```
import * as ss from 'socket.io-stream';

export default {
    name: "InputForm",
    methods: {
        sendFile(file: File) {
            const stream = ss.createStream();
            ss(socket).emit("stream", stream, { name: file.name });
            file.stream().pipeTo(stream);
        }
    }
}
```

The import itself doesn't cause any issues however as soon as I try to use the `ss` object I'm getting the above `ReferenceError: process is not defined`.

I think it's important to note that to get the import working I had to create a `declarations.d.ts` file with `declare module 'socket.io-stream'` inside. I also don't get any autocompletion for `ss` methods.

I have also run browserify as explained in the github page of `socket.io-stream` however that didn't change anything.

Does anyone have an idea of where the problem might stem from and what I've done wrong? Also how to use `socket.io-stream` on the browser